# Android start activity from RemoteViews but resume the activity

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, remoteview

I want to start activity from RemoteViews. My app has only one activity and many fragments. When I start the activity from notification, the activity starts from splash fragment. I want to resume the activity if it is available and not destroyed. This is my current code:

```
Intent openAppIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent openAppPI = PendingIntent.getActivity
            (this,0,openAppIntent,0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.viewId,openAppPI);
```

Comment: you can send some flags with your intent using `putExtras()`

Comment: Which flags exactly should I put? I searched that but I couldn't find a good result for this purpose.

Comment: flags as boolean values that which fragment should open when clicked from notifications